# When "making" the proof for the permutations formula, where does $n-r+1$ come from?

Tags: probability, permutations, proof-explanation, combinations

I am trying to search the proof of the permutation formula, and usually what you want to do to find all the possible permutations of $n$ elements on $r$ blanks, is to use factorials. So this get you to
$P(n,r)=n(n-1)(n-2)...$ until you reach the $r$th element. Where does the $n-r+1$ comes from?

It obviously gets you to the number of numbers that you need to multiply in order to find the permutations. For example, there are $10$ objects, and you want to put them onto $4$ blankets:
$10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7$, so you have $10!$ divided by $6!$, because you want to eliminate the $1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 6$ in the $10!$ in order to get the $10 \times 9 \times 8 \times 7$, so you got $P(n,r)= n!/(n-r)!$ which can be expressed in the second paragraph on this text, then, how do I get the $n-r+1$, and how do I express it in the permutation formula?

Comment: The 6 in $6!$ is $n-r = 10 - 4 = 6$. If you look at $P(n,r)$ as $(n-0)(n-1) \cdots (n-5)$ you can see that that is 6 consecutive integers starting with $10$ and ending with $5$.

Comment: yes, but why is the formula writen in that way?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if you divide $n!$ by $(n- r)!$, you are dividing:

$$1 \times 2 \times \ldots \times n$$
by
$$1 \times 2 \times \ldots \times (n-r)$$
Each of the first $n-r$ terms in the first product cancels with the corresponding term in the second product. What is the first term that doesn't cancel?

Comment: of course i understand that, however im curious of why when you have n elements and you want to order them in different ways on r "blanks" for examples, you start by "using" n!, until getting to the rth term, with n-r+1, (n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)...(n-r+1)

Comment: That's just reading the division as I described it in my answer from right to left rather than left to right.